# How to increment the date value of sap.ui.commons.DatePicker

Tags: javascript, sapui5

For a simple leave application in UI5, i need to increment or decrement the date of a new sap.ui.commons.DatePicker by one day on each button press, how can I get and set the new date?

The problem is that the DatePicker returns only a string of the Date. I tried already new Date(datePicker.getYyyymmdd()) but then I cat an Invalide date back.

Comment: I'd recommend moment.js if you need to do more with dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution for your parsing the string to a date object can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10608559/5747152) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10638617/5747152).

You should also consider to switch to [sap.m.DatePicker](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.DatePicker.html) since [sap.ui.commons.DatePicker](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.commons.DatePicker.html) is deprecated in version >=1.38 (don't know which version you are using). The sap.m.DatePicker also has the method [getDateValue](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.DatePicker.html#getDateValue), which should already return a date object.

Comment: I changed now to sap.m.DatePicker. Somehow in the Documentation it isn't marked as deprecated.

Comment: Actually the whole sap.ui.commons library is deprecated and yes, it is marked: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.commons.DatePicker.html

Answer (score 0):

Date manipulation in Javascript is really easy. If you want to add a day to a date, it would be `date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1)`, and subtracting works in the same fashion: `date.setDate(date.getDate() - 1)`.

You just have to get the `yyyymmdd` format as used by the date-picker back into Javascript's native `date` type. As mentioned by @R.Schmitt, you could of course use any of Javascript tricks from Stackoverflow. On the other hand, the UI5 team has already built this logic for you in the DateFormat class, so it's probably neatest to leverage that.

To get from a `yyyymmdd` to `date`, you could use:

```
sap.ui.core.format.DateFormat.getDateInstance({pattern : "YYYYMMdd" }).parse(date);
```

To get from a `date` to `yyyymmdd` format, you can use:

```
sap.ui.core.format.DateFormat.getDateInstance({pattern : "YYYYMMdd"}).format(yyymmdd);
```

To see the Javascript date calcluation and UI5's DateFormat class in action, have a look at this jsbin:
http://jsbin.com/xeyiwic/1/edit?html,output

Comment: I think date manipulation in JavaScript really sucks. If you have used moment.js once you'd never want to go back again :)

Comment: If you come from a Java world, you'll know what a blessing the native Dates in Javascript already are. I agree with you that moment.js makes that experience even better.