# Convert Date String(yymmdd) to Date Object in JS

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, date-parsing

I have a date string in "yymmdd" format i want to convert it into date object in JS
the input string is "161208"
I have tried code below

```
var mydate = new Date(InputDate);
```

but it says invalid date.
Here is the fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/4ry0hL4t/

the basic need is that, I have a date string in "yymmdd" format and i have to convert it to different date formats like ("yyyy/mm/dd, yy-mm-dd","yy/mm").

Comment: Try [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) library, that's a pretty good library for parsing. Javascripts and dates was never really such a good match (eg: January is the 0 month, not 1st ...)

Comment: Maybe this post can help you further. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10607935/convert-returned-string-yyyymmdd-to-date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41123180/javascript-new-datestring-compatible-for-most-browsers-dec-2016).
Basically you first need to give a proper format to your string. You can either do it manually or use moment.js.

```
stringFormat = moment(dateObject).format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss");
date = new Date(stringFormat);
```

[This](http://dygraphs.com/date-formats.html) is also really helpful to understand how the different string formats are compatible with different browsers.

Comment: I was trying not to use an external JS but had to use it after all, momentJS solved the issue.

Comment: @AdilWaqar I'm glad to hear that, and indeed moment.js is a really good tool!

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure if this is what you're after?

```
var s = '161208';
var dt = new Date('20' + s.substring(0, 2) + '-' + s.substring(2, 4) + '-' + s.substring(4));
```

Comment: That's the kind of assumption that kept me very busy in the late 90s ;)