# Find difference in days between two integers representing dates in the format "yyyymmdd" using math skills with javascript

Tags: javascript

Hey how can you find the number of days difference in javascript between two dates with a "yyyymmdd" format?

For instance 20210206 - 20210825 will return 619, however these dates are actually only 200 days apart.

Also, I have to do with the dates as just integers. I don't have access to any special date functions.

Is there a math genius out there who knows what to do?

Comment: Also, I have to do with the dates as just integers. I don't have access to any special date functions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the number of days between two dates in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542938/how-do-i-get-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates-in-javascript)

Comment: What about the date functions built into the javascript language?

Comment: Another one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224834/get-difference-between-2-dates-in-javascript

Comment: No that doesn't help. I have to use straight up math skills. They aren't actually dates, they are just integers representing dates.

Comment: You need a way to **substr()** to return the value in a Date format.
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substr.asp

Comment: Yeah, I guess if there is a way to convert the numbers into an actual Date object, that could help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10607935/convert-returned-string-yyyymmdd-to-date

Comment: Thanks, ponury-kostek. That link is perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`String.substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) to split the string into 3 parts (year, month, date) and pass them as parameters in the `Date` object, then subtract and divide by 86400000:

```js
function convertToDate(s){
  return new Date(s.substring(0, 4) - 1, s.substring(4, 6) -1, s.substring(6));
}
const first = "20210206";
const second = "20210825";
const diff = Math.floor(Math.abs((convertToDate(first) - convertToDate(second)) / 86400000))
console.log(diff)
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks.

Comment: There is a time wait before it will allow me to accept, haha.